# SSIS export to CSV Flat File Destination task, error The code page on input column is ... and is required to be

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I get this error on a File Destination Task,   do you know what the cause is and how to fix it ?

```
Package Validation Error

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at export data to csv [Flat File Destination [187]]: The code page on input column "..." (958) is 1252 and is required to be 65001.
```

ta

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is caused by a clash in code pages between 1252 (i.e. Windows-1252) in SQL Server and 65001 (i.e. UTF-8) that your CSV file is expecting.

I believe one solution to the issue would be to `CAST` your source columns to `NVARCHAR` in the initial `SELECT` from the database, or use a Data Conversion task to convert them to Unicode strings.

An alternative would be set the code page in the Flat File Connection Manager to **1252 ANSI - Latin**.

Comment: yes, it worked in both ways, convert to NVARCHAR , but also using Data derivation task. I have not tried to set the Flat File Connection Manager to 1252 ANSI - Latin.   Thanks a lot!

Comment: SQL Server is such a stupid engine. Of course `varchar` is a subset of `nvarchar`. I don't get it why it needs an explicit cast.

Comment: The alternative to set the Flat File Connection Manager is my choice!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where My error was as follows:

`The code page on Flat File Destination.Inputs[Flat File Destination Input].Columns[Number] is 65001 and is required to be 1252.`

Then I was doing google and I found very interesting and correct results from the below website: [Here in the question, itself answer is given. After that, I just change code-page-1252 in flat-file property from connection manager and it worked for me](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/answered-flat-file-problem-input-column-is-1252-and-is-required-to-be-65001)

Comment: Acknowledging the source of your answer is applauded. Adding the important points into the answer is the preferred approach.